# Can't install any Linux distro

Tags: 12.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my step-son's netbook and I checked and his hard disk seems to be failing and i keep getting an error message that Ubuntu is unable to install due to hard disk failure. I was wondering how and if it is possible to install Ubuntu on this hard disk without it giving me an error message. I have tried the alternate install disk image and the regular desktop image and get basically the same error message. Is there a way to somehow override this and get it installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hard disk is failing, it needs to be replaced. Even if you managed to get an OS installed on it again, the drive could become worse off quickly enough, and the system could become unusable at an unknown point in the future, and render the disk completely inaccessible, and the data unrecoverable. Your best option is to replace the drive.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a failing hard drive I would buy a new hard drive.

You could try getting a cheap external hard drive and putting it on that. If it is in fact the hard drive going bad, there would not be a way to install it.

If somebody else knows otherwise let me know. I would be very interested if it is in fact possible! I am pretty sure it isn't though... Sorry.